# Identical classes casting?

Tags: java, class, casting

Suppose I have two classes A and B. Both are identical (same atributes, methods, etc), but they are named different.

There's some safe way, in Java, to cast a B object as an A object?

Comment: Nope.  Why do you want to anyway?  (Unless you mean for one to extend the other, or have them both implement a common interface.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot cast one to the other if they belong in different class hierarchies. They are **not identical**, even if they *happen* to share the same attributes and methods. Additionally, if they belong to the same class hierarchy, *but* one is not a superclass of the other, you can't cast across the same class hierarchy either. There's only upcasting and downcasting within a hierarchy.

However, you can pass objects of either class to a certain method if

- They implement the same interface, or extend the same superclass, and
- That method accepts a parameter that is of the interface's or superclass's type

(And that's the basic premise of [polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).)

Comment: It's not the basic premise of polymorphism, it's a java thing. A and B are both sub-type of each other, casting between them is painless.

Comment: @double_squeeze Where does it say that A and B are sub-types of each other?

Comment: @Sentry they are equal, they are thus sub-type of each other.

Comment: @double_squeeze No, they may be equal, but not identical. Hence, there are not sub-types of each other. Like the answer says, they are not identical if they belong to different class hierarchies.

Comment: @Sentry They are equal and identical. The fact that java doesn't recognize it is another issue. In many languages with a decent compiler, those classes are interchangeable. Java cannot decide it, but they still ARE sub-type of each other. Actually even in Java they are sub-type-ish of each other: if you take working code with an element of type A, and replace it with an element of type B, with all the type annotations, it will still work.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't, unless they have a common parent with the same attributes, but you can use the [`copyProperties()`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) method from [common.beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to pass every property from one bean to another.

Another way would be to create a subclass for A which could delegate calls to a B and vice versa.

A third way would be to use a [proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

But the last two solutions only works for method calls, if your attributes are public you can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you could use reflection to copy properties.
Then, create a wrapper function to "cast" the class; example:

```
class A {
    public cc=0;
}
class B {
    public cc=2;
}

B mycast(A a){
    B b=new B();

    for(String name in a)
        b.setProperty(name,a.getProperty(name));

    return b;
}
```

Notes:

- Been some time since I've used Java, so the above should be seen as pseudo-code more or less, especially the JS-style reflection.
- I suggest you use an interface instead; they were made specifically to do what you want (and more, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking the only way two Java classes can be identical is if they satisfy the identity a == b. Two classes with the same members and different names or packages don't do that, also by definition.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to manually set the data in class A to the data in class B